# Pickle with Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, bdd, pickle

I'm super new to ruby web development and have been experimenting with Sinatra.  I like what I've seen of Cucumber/Pickle for BDD style testing.  I've got Cucumber configured and working but am now stumped on integrating Pickle.  Is it compatible with Sinatra?  All the examples I've seen on the web are focused on Rails mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the [templates](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle/tree/master/rails_generators/pickle/templates) the pickle rails generator uses and tailor them to your needs.

From what the generator does, you'd need a `features/support/pickle.rb` file like this:

```
require 'pickle/world'
# Example of configuring pickle:
#
# Pickle.configure do |config|
#   config.adapters = [:machinist]
#   config.map 'I', 'myself', 'me', 'my', :to => 'user: "me"'
# end
# require 'pickle/path/world'
# require 'pickle/email/world'
```

And you'd need to pull in the `pickle_steps.rb` into your steps directory. There's also templates for paths & for email specific steps.

Does that help?

Comment: That does help.  I had wondered about trying what you've suggested but being so new to it all I worried Pickle was maybe a Rails only thing.  Thanks for you input.